# How to convert string to boolean php

Tags: php, string, casting, boolean

How can I convert string to `boolean`?

```
$string = 'false';

$test_mode_mail = settype($string, 'boolean');

var_dump($test_mode_mail);

if($test_mode_mail) echo 'test mode is on.';
```

it returns,

> boolean true

but it should be `boolean false`.

Comment: Why any answered about $bool=!!$string1 ?

Comment: @zloctb because it doesn't answer the question. `!!$string1` would return a boolean indicative of the string outlined in the top rated answer.

Answer (score 484, accepted):

Strings always evaluate to boolean true unless they have a value that's considered "empty" by PHP (taken from the [documentation for `empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)):

1. `""` (an empty string);
2. `"0"` (0 as a string)

If you need to set a boolean based on the text value of a string, then you'll need to check for the presence or otherwise of that value.

```
$test_mode_mail = $string === 'true'? true: false;
```

EDIT: the above code is intended for clarity of understanding.  In actual use the following code may be more appropriate:

```
$test_mode_mail = ($string === 'true');
```

or maybe use of the `filter_var` function may cover more boolean values:

```
filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

`filter_var` covers a whole range of values, including the truthy values `"true"`, `"1"`, `"yes"` and `"on"`. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_boolean.asp) for more details.

Comment: I recommend to always use strict comparison, if you're not sure what you're doing: `$string === 'true'`

Comment: I found this - `filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);` is it a good thing?

Comment: The ternary doesn't seem necessary.  Why not just set $test_mode_mail to the value of the inequality?  $test_mode_mail = $string === 'true'

Comment: But what about 1/0, TRUE/FALSE? I think @lauthiamkok 's answer is the best.

Comment: What if you have something like this: `$test_ = "(3 < 5)";` You wouldn't want to use `eval()` due to the security risks involved...

Comment: @FelipeTadeo I'm talking about how PHP evaluates strings with respect to boolean operations, I never mentioned eval() and I'd never recommending using it under any circumstances.  The string "(3 < 5)" will be evaluated by PHP as boolean true because it's not empty.

Comment: Just to clarify why triple equals is a bad idea;  if ('true' === true) evaluates to false where if ('true' == true) evaluates to true.

Comment: @AlexBarker Actually that's exactly why == is bad and why you should use === instead.  Non-strict evaluation can cause horrid bugs such as unexpected type juggling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098104/odd-behaviour-in-a-switch-statement and unexpected object graph traversal resulting in endless recursion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460011/in-array-on-objects-with-circular-references

Comment: I will also add the part in which you make the text lowercase (or uppercase) 
**strtolower(trim($string))** because if the value is 'TRUE', it won't match the 'true' string, so the result will be false

Comment: I think the base function boolval() should be mentioned, because its usefull when converting array values to booleans (array_map('boolval'...)., although not the question directly...

Answer (score 895):

This method was posted by @lauthiamkok in the comments.  I'm posting it here as an answer to call more attention to it.

Depending on your needs, you should consider using `filter_var()` with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` flag.

```
filter_var(      true, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true
filter_var(    'true', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true
filter_var(         1, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true
filter_var(       '1', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true
filter_var(      'on', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true
filter_var(     'yes', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true

filter_var(     false, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
filter_var(   'false', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
filter_var(         0, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
filter_var(       '0', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
filter_var(     'off', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
filter_var(      'no', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
filter_var('asdfasdf', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
filter_var(        '', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
filter_var(      null, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false
```

Comment: I really like this solution for setting booleans based on WordPress shortcode attributes that have values such as true, false, on, 0, etc. Great answer, should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: `filter_var($answer, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)` worked even better for me. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#121263

Comment: !! Important note !! filter_var returns also FALSE if the filter fails. This may create some problems.

Comment: THIS answer is the answer `filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);` usable in almost all situations. I'm surprised the OP marked the other answer as accepted.

Answer (score 44):

The String `"false"`  is actually considered a `"TRUE"` value by PHP.
The documentation says:

> To explicitly convert a value to boolean, use the (bool) or (boolean)
>   casts. However, in most cases the cast is unnecessary, since a value
>   will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control
>   structure requires a boolean argument.
>
> See also Type Juggling.
>
> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

so if you do:

```
$bool = (boolean)"False";
```

or

```
$test = "false";
$bool = settype($test, 'boolean');
```

in both cases `$bool` will be `TRUE`. So you have to do it manually, like GordonM suggests.

Comment: Euhm, ofcourse the lower one returns false. In fact, it throws a fatal :) "Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference". $a = 'False'; settype($a,'boolean'); var_dump($a); will indeed return false.

Answer (score 20):

When working with JSON, I had to send a Boolean value via `$_POST`. I had a similar problem when I did something like:

```
if ( $_POST['myVar'] == true) {
    // do stuff;
}
```

In the code above, my Boolean was converted into a JSON string.

To overcome this, you can decode the string using `json_decode()`:

```
//assume that : $_POST['myVar'] = 'true';
 if( json_decode('true') == true ) { //do your stuff; }
```

(This should normally work with Boolean values converted to string and sent to the server also by other means, i.e., other than using JSON.)

Answer (score 18):

you can use json_decode to decode that boolean

```
$string = 'false';
$boolean = json_decode($string);
if($boolean) {
  // Do something
} else {
  //Do something else
}
```

Comment: json_decode will also transform to integer if the given string is an integer

Comment: Yes, that's true, but its mentioned that the string is holding boolean value

Answer (score 12):

```
(boolean)json_decode(strtolower($string))
```

It handles all possible variants of `$string`

```
'true'  => true
'True'  => true
'1'     => true
'false' => false
'False' => false
'0'     => false
'foo'   => false
''      => false
```

Comment: What about `on` and `off`?

Comment: @Cyclonecode it won't handle it the same as `вкл` and `выкл`.

Answer (score 10):

If your "boolean" variable comes from a global array such as $_POST and $_GET, you can use `filter_input()` filter function.

Example for POST:

```
$isSleeping  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'is_sleeping',  FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

If your "boolean" variable comes from other source you can use `filter_var()` filter function.

Example:

```
filter_var('true', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true
```

Answer (score 10):

```
filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);

$string = 1; // true
$string ='1'; // true
$string = 'true'; // true
$string = 'trUe'; // true
$string = 'TRUE'; // true
$string = 0; // false
$string = '0'; // false
$string = 'false'; // false
$string = 'False'; // false
$string = 'FALSE'; // false
$string = ''; // false
$string = 'sgffgfdg'; // null
```

You must specify

```
FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE
```

otherwise you'll get always false even if $string contains something else.

Answer (score 5):

the easiest thing to do is this:

```
$str = 'TRUE';

$boolean = strtolower($str) == 'true' ? true : false;

var_dump($boolean);
```

Doing it this way, you can loop through a series of 'true', 'TRUE', 'false' or 'FALSE' and get the string value to a boolean.

Comment: You could make the above a bit simpler by doing `$boolean = strtolower($str) == 'true';`

Answer (score 3):

Other answers are over complicating things. This question is simply **logic** question. Just get your statement right.

```
$boolString = 'false';
$result = 'true' === $boolString;
```

Now your answer will be either

- `false`, if the string was `'false'`,
- or `true`, if your string was `'true'`.

I have to note that `filter_var( $boolString, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );` still will be a better option **if** you need to have strings like `on/yes/1` as alias for `true`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function stringToBool($string){
    return ( mb_strtoupper( trim( $string)) === mb_strtoupper ("true")) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

or

```
function stringToBool($string) {
    return filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by **@GordonM** is good.
But it would fail if the `$string` is already `true` (ie, the string isn't a string but boolean TRUE)...which seems illogical.

Extending his answer, I'd use:

```
$test_mode_mail = ($string === 'true' OR $string === true));
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it in a way that will cast any case insensitive version of the string "false" to the boolean FALSE, but will behave using the normal php casting rules for all other strings. I think this is the best way to prevent unexpected behavior.

```
$test_var = 'False';
$test_var = strtolower(trim($test_var)) == 'false' ? FALSE : $test_var;
$result = (boolean) $test_var;
```

Or as a function:

```
function safeBool($test_var){
    $test_var = strtolower(trim($test_var)) == 'false' ? FALSE : $test_var;
    return (boolean) $test_var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the settype method too!

```php
$string = 'false';
$boolean = settype($string,"boolean");
var_dump($boolean); //see 0 or 1
```

Comment: This is invalid PHP code. The correct case for these terms should be `echo` and `settype()`. PHP also requires semicolons at the end of every line. I don't know how this got 2 upvotes, and was also edited by someone who didn't know these absolute basics of PHP that you learn on day 1.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting confused with wordpress shortcode attributes, I decided to write a custom function to handle all possibilities. maybe it's useful for someone:

```php
function stringToBool($str){
    if($str === 'true' || $str === 'TRUE' || $str === 'True' || $str === 'on' || $str === 'On' || $str === 'ON'){
        $str = true;
    }else{
        $str = false;
    }
    return $str;
}
stringToBool($atts['onOrNot']);
```

Comment: i was looking for help in the first place, but did not find anything as easy as as i hoped. that's why i wrote my own function. feel free to use it.

Comment: Perhaps lower the string to you don't need all the or conditions `$str = strtolower($str); return ($str == 'true' || $str == 'on');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'false';

$test_mode_mail = $string === 'false' ? false : true;

var_dump($test_mode_mail);

if($test_mode_mail) echo 'test mode is on.';
```

You have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in php-8 could be:

```
function convertToBool(string $value): bool
{
     return match($value) {
         'true' => true,
         default => false,
     };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited to show a working solution using `preg_match();` to return boolean true or false based on a string containing true. This may be heavy in comparison to other answers but can easily be adjusted to fit any string to boolean need.

```
$test_mode_mail = 'false';      
$test_mode_mail = 'true'; 
$test_mode_mail = 'true is not just a perception.';

$test_mode_mail = gettype($test_mode_mail) !== 'boolean' ? (preg_match("/true/i", $test_mode_mail) === 1 ? true:false):$test_mode_mail;

echo ($test_mode_mail === true ? 'true':'false')." ".gettype($test_mode_mail)." ".$test_mode_mail."<br>";
```

Comment: This is not what was asked. The question is how to convert a string into boolean.

Comment: @mrded I have edited the answer to be a working one as your comment was correct.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is to check against an array of values that you consider true.

```
$wannabebool = "false";
$isTrue = ["true",1,"yes","ok","wahr"];
$bool = in_array(strtolower($wannabebool),$isTrue);
```

Answer (score -4):

You should be able to cast to a boolean using (bool) but I'm not sure without checking whether this works on the strings "true" and "false".

This might be worth a pop though

```
$myBool = (bool)"False"; 

if ($myBool) {
    //do something
}
```

It is worth knowing that the following will evaluate to the boolean False when put inside

```
if()
```

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Everytyhing else will evaluate to true.

As descried here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: In response to the guess in your first paragraph: using an explicit cast to boolean will convert `"false"` to `true`.

Comment: This will print "true" `$myBool = (bool)"False"; 

if ($myBool) {
    echo "true";
}`

Comment: This is wrong, strings are evaluated as true unless they contain "" or "0".