# Infinite recursive PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Is there any way to detect if a PHP array is recursive?

For example, consider the following code:

```
   $a = ['value', &$a];
```

How can I loop through the array $a and detect the recursion?

Comment: See also [How to check for circular references in PHP when recursively parsing an associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880770/how-to-check-for-circular-references-in-php-when-recursively-parsing-an-associat)

Comment: Thank you. It is missed that PHP has a native function to detect recursive arrays.