# Passing a boolean through PHP GET

Tags: php, get, boolean

Pretty simple question here, not sure the answer though. Can I pass a boolean variable through get? For example:

```
http://example.com/foo.php?myVar=true
```

then I have

```
$hopefullyBool = $_GET['myVar'];
```

Is `$hopefullyBool` a boolean or a string? My hypothesis is that it's a string but can someone let me know? Thanks

Comment: It's a string. GET parms are not typed.

Comment: No, you will need to make it boolean

Comment: Use `myVar=1` or `myVar=0` instead. Then you can easily convert to booean in your PHP script.

Comment: good point. That's what I thought, thanks guys

Comment: Try: [how-to-convert-string-to-boolean-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336861/how-to-convert-string-to-boolean-php)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

All GET parameters will be strings (or an array of strings) in PHP.  Use [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) (or [filter_input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)) and `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN`:

> Returns **TRUE** for "1", "true", "on" and "yes". Returns **FALSE** otherwise.
>
> If **FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE** is set, **FALSE** is returned only for "0", "false", "off", "no", and "", and **NULL** is returned for all non-boolean values.

```
$hopefullyBool = filter_var($_GET['myVar'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

For INPUT vars that can be arrays there is [filter_var_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php) and [filter_input_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php).

Another way to get the type boolean, pass something that evaluates to `true` or `false` like string `0` or `1`:

```
http://example.com/foo.php?myVar=0
http://example.com/foo.php?myVar=1
```

Then cast to boolean:

```
$hopefullyBool = (bool)$_GET['myVar'];
```

If you want to pass string `true` or `false` then another way:

```
$hopefullyBool = $_GET['myVar'] == 'true' ? true : false;
```

But I would say that `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` was meant for this.

Comment: Is there any difference in this one and
"$hopefullyBool = 'true' === $_GET['myVar'];"
?

Comment: K, thanks, so it should be the same then. I was worried that I used the wrong way.

Comment: (bool) would convert "false" to true

Comment: @John: Yes, that's why my example for `(bool)` uses 0 and 1 not "true" and "false".

Comment: There is an exception:

`http://example.com/foo.php?myVar[]=0`
`http://example.com/foo.php?myVar[]=1`

Here `myVar` param will be _array_ in PHP.

Comment: @DanAlexson90: That's why there is https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver, that's a comment regarding "_All_ GET parameters will be strings in PHP."

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid an if statement:

```
filter_var('true', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);  
//bool(true)

filter_var('false', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); 
//bool(false)
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be passed as a string. While you can convert it using the bool cast, it is recommended to not do so in some cases.

You would be better off doing if myVar == "True"

Be cautious:

```
>>> bool("foo")
True
>>> bool("")
False
```

Empty strings evaluate to False, but everything else evaluates to True. So this should not be used for any kind of parsing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to do it. Firstly we could use PHP's in-built `(boolean)` method, which casts a string value to a boolean:

`$hopefullyBool = (boolean)$_GET['myVar'];`

This would result in a boolean value of `true` or `false` depending on the value of the string in `$_GET['myVar']`.

From v5.2.1 upwards, we can also use `json_decode()` to ascertain the boolean value:

`$hopefullyBool = json_decode($_GET['myVar]);`

The `json_decode()` method parses a JSON Object (which is a string) into a PHP variable, and takes type-casting into account. As a result, the string `'true'` from the URL param will be cast to the boolean `true`.

You could use both of the above methods in tandem, using:

`$hopefullyBool = (boolean)json_decode($_GET['myVar]);`

To mitigate against uppercase characters being passed in the URL param (eg `?myVar=True` or `?myVar=FALSE`), you should use the `strtolower()` method, which will convert a string to all lowercase letters:

`$hopefullyBool = (boolean)json_decode(strtolower($_GET['myVar]));`

Finally, we'll want to fall-back to `false` if the parameter is not present in the URL's query string, otherwise PHP will throw an Undefined Index notice. To do this, we can use the `isset()` method:

```
$hopefullyBool = false;
if ( isset($_GET['myVar']) ) {
    $hopefullyBool = (boolean)json_decode(strtolower($_GET['myVar]));
}
```

To shorten this, you could initiate `$hopefullyBool` using a conditional statement like so:

`$hopefullyBool = isset($_GET['myVar']) && (boolean)json_decode(strtolower($_GET['myVar']));`

Answer (score 0):

if I'm sure that the only thing being passed is a boolean,
I normally just check if it's equal to String "true"
if it is, then it return true, if not then it return false

`$is_true= $_GET['is_true'] == "true";`