# Convert String 'true' or 'false' to interger '1' or '0'

Tags: php, string, boolean

I want to convert String variable 'true' or 'false' to int '1' or '0'.

To achieve this I'm trying like this

```
(int) (boolean) 'true' //gives 1
(int) (boolean) 'false' //gives 1 but i need 0 here
```

I now I can using array like `array('false','true');`
or using `if($myboolean=='true'){$int=1;}`

But this way is less efficient.

Is there another more efficient way like this `(int) (boolean) 'true'` ?

#### I know this question has been asked. but I have not found the answer

Comment: Why don't you try casting your data one-by-one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336861/how-to-convert-string-to-boolean-php

Comment: @MammaMia I've done it but have not found an answer

Comment: @DrewJex, it's not the same question. lqbal wants an integer, not a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use unary operator

```
int $my_int = $myboolean=='true' ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think all the right answers are just different ways. and sorry I can only determine a correct answer that is the way that I think is most efficient. I appreciate all the answers

Answer (score 13):

Strings always evaluate to boolean true unless they have a value that's considered "empty" by PHP.

Depending on your needs, you should consider using filter_var() with the FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN flag.

```
(int)filter_var('true', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
(int)filter_var('false', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

Comment: Thanks @Farhad Mortezapour. I think your answer is most efficient

Comment: ahh thats cool, you can filter a string to validate if its a boolean... cool.

Answer (score 1):

the string "false" is *truthy*. That's why `(int) (boolean) "false"` return 1 instead of 0. If you want to get a `false` boolean value from a string, you can pass an empty string `(int) (boolean) ""`. More info [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Comment: this is very helpful. but not a solution. because i have data true or false

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
$int = 5 - strlen($myboolean);

// 5 - strlen('true')  => 1
// 5 - strlen('false') => 0
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
// ---- fonction ----

function b2i(b){return 5 - b.length}



//------------ debug -----------

for(b of ['true','True','TRUE','false','False','FALSE'])
{
  console.log("b2i('"+b+"') = ", b2i(b));
}
```

Comment: It's the shorter one, faster one, and it's case insensitive. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = true;

if ($variable) {
     $convert = 1;
}
else {
    $convert = 0;
}

echo $convert
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think all the right answers are just different ways. and sorry I can only determine a correct answer that is the way that I think is most efficient. I appreciate all the answers

Comment: The question, I believe, was how to convert a string to a 1 or 0, not a boolean value.

Comment: cast a string to a int. `$a = "1";` to cast do `$b = (int)$a` then do your if statement on the variable `$b`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`echo (int) (boolean) '';`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think all the right answers are just different ways. and sorry I can only determine a correct answer that is the way that I think is most efficient. I appreciate all the answers

Answer (score -1):

Normally just `$Int = (int)$Boolean` would work fine, or you could just add a + in front of your variable, like this:

```
$Boolean = true; 

var_dump(+$Boolean);

ouputs: int(1);
```

also, `(int)(bool)'true'` should work too

Comment: this works if my data is boolean type. but my data is string

Comment: (int) (bool) 'false' --> true, which is the problem