# PHP check if a variable is true or false

Tags: php

i wonder why i could not find an answer from searching through google?
how do you compare if a boolean variable is true or false, i have the ff code:
the value of `$input['appointed_phases1'] is true` while the value for `$input['appointed_phases2'] is false`:

```
    $appointed_phases = 0;
    if($input['appointed_phases1'] == true && $input['appointed_phases2'] == true){
        $appointed_phases = 3;
    }elseif($input['appointed_phases1'] == true && $input['appointed_phases2'] == false){
        $appointed_phases = 1;
    }elseif($input['appointed_phases1'] == false && $input['appointed_phases2'] == true){
        $appointed_phases = 2;
    }else{
        $appointed_phases = 0;
    }
```

for some reason the value of `$appointed_phases` is always 3

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump($input['appointed_phases1'])` and `var_dump($input['appointed_phases2'])`. I suspect they are strings and not actual boolean values. In which case type juggling will make both comparisons equal to `true` thus making the first condition always trigger.

Comment: You can make it much simpler with binary bits. When both `2` and `1` are set, it's `3`, when only `2` is set, it's `2`, when only `1` is set, it's one, else, it's zero.

Comment: When checking for a boolean you need to always use the strict comparison operator `===` not `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `$input['appointed_phases1']` contains a string value.
In PHP, any string value that is not empty evaluates to true.

See this question:
[How to convert string to boolean php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336861/how-to-convert-string-to-boolean-php)

You can cast the value of `$input['appointed_phases1']` to a boolean, or you can compare this value with `'true'` instead of `true`.