# PHP exit if one post value set and another is empty

Tags: php

Right, I've been trying and trying, but I simply cannot get this to work. I have two password fields that the user needs to match to make the script continue. I already have this:

```
if ($_POST['password']!= $_POST['password1'])
 {
     echo("Oops! Password did not match! Try again. ");
     exit();
 }
 else{
 }
```

So this script works, except if the user doesn't set a value for `password1`, it still goes continues the rest of the script, without exiting. I imagine this is to do with the fact it's null/empty or whatever.

So I made a script to stop it from continuing if `password` had a value but `password1` was empty, but so far, I've not been able to get any results.

This is what I have so far:

```
 if (empty($_POST['password1']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
      echo("Oops! Password did not match! Try again. ");
     exit();
} 
else{
}
```

Comment: What happens if you compare with !== instead of !=

Comment: Maybe PHP is type-juggling in some insane way resulting in an empty password box being cast to 0 and the string in password1 (which doesn't start with a number) also getting cast to 0.  Other than that I don't see how the problem you're describing can happen, if one string is empty and the other isn't then they can't be equal.  Maybe using !== instead of != would help if it's a type juggling issue.

Comment: Hmm, yes, using `!==` worked better. Someone said I should use `!=` whne I wrote the script. Why I listened, I don't know :P

Comment: I figured that would be the case.  If you use loose comparison (==, !=, etc) and the variables being compared are of different type, PHP will try to cast one or both of them to the same type, sometimes with unpredictable results The strict comparisons (===, !==, etc) force PHP to treat different types as unequal even if they have the same value (so 0 == 0.0, is true, but 0 === 0.0 is false).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098104/odd-behaviour-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: Hmm, so after doing it, and using a few of the answers other people have put, I'm finsing that the script exists no matter what. If I don't put exit, the script still goes through :/ Perhaps a redirect may help

Comment: Guys, I'm going to kill myself.

The error was in the form (albeit, my original code wasn't very good anyway) 

I'd set the input type to password1 rather than the name

Oh my God

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the best way is to check first that both fields are set and not empty, which can be done with `empty()` in one shot. Then, check if both fields are equal to each other.

```
if (empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password1'])) {
    exit('Please fill in all password fields!');
}
if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password1']) {
    exit('Password confirmation did not match!');
}
```

To be on the safe side you should also check on the fields with [`is_scalar()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php) before using the `$_POST` values to prevent a malicious user to submit an array in `$_POST['password']` and make the server throw an error.

I would also suggest enforcing a minimal length with [`mb_strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) so users use at least six characters for their password, for example. We don't need to check the length on both password fields since we'll check that they're equal to each other.

In the end, you could have code that looks something like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password1'])
   || !is_scalar($_POST['password']) || !is_scalar($_POST['password1']))
{
    exit('Please fill in all password fields!');
}
if (mb_strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
    exit('Please use a password of at least 6 characters.');
}
if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password1']) {
    exit('Password confirmation did not match!');
}
```

Comment: IF (empty ($_POST ['password'])) would cover all those checks

Comment: @GordonM You're right. I like `strlen()` because you probably want to have at least a password of, say, six characters, but I'll update my post accordingly.

Comment: @ljacqu since we are trying to find the length of user input, it is much better to use `mb_strlen()` in case some cyrillic or other multibyte characters find there way into the input.

Comment: @NickJ Thanks! I hope it's OK that I've updated my post to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['password']) || !isset($_POST['password1'])) {
    $pass1 = trim($_POST['password']);
    $pass2 = trim($_POST['password1']);
    if (
        empty($pass1) ||
        empty($pass2) ||
        $pass1 !== $pass2
    ) {
        echo("Oops! Password did not match! Try again. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need both !isset and empty, just empty on its own is fine.

Comment: This actually worked, the thing is, I need the script to exit as well as echo. However, when I put `exit`, the script exists each time the page loads

Comment: Even isset() and empty() is still not enough. Empty will fail if the user mistakenly press the space key. Hence introducing a string " "

Comment: Not needed both isset and empty both here.

Comment: @GordonM and @NaincyGupta - True, but is better still to use them both anyway, chances are if you are using `isset()`, you will need to use `empty()` as well (for one reason or another).

Comment: Sure! it is better now. POINT TO NOTE: If that validation succeeds. It is not expected that you use either $pass1 or $pass2 for your SQL Query instead $_POST['password'] or $_POST['password1'] will be preferred. Reason: trim() was applied on the original password to get $pass1 and $pass2. Imagine when a user used "passwordme " as password. Applying $trim() on it will return "passwordme" instead of "passwordme ". Hence modifying user's original input.

Comment: Given that a space at the end or beginning of a string is typically a mistake, it makes sense. But what concerns me is someone directly using a post variable in an SQL query. That's just begging for an injection attack. You should be [storing hashes of the passwords, not the actual passowords](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q)

Comment: `trim($_POST['password'];)` should be `trim($_POST['password']);` – same for _password1_.

Answer (score 0):

Use empty(); 
!empty($_POST['test']) === ( isset($_POST['test']) && !$_POST['test'] )

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['password'], $_POST['password1']))
{
     $password = trim($_POST['password']);
     $password1 = trim($_POST['password1']);
     if($password=="" || $password1=='')
     {
         echo "Oops! Field canot be blank !! ");
         exit;
     }
     else if($password != $password1)
     {
         echo "Oops! Password did not match! Try again. !! ");
         exit;
     }
     else
     { 
           // do here your code
     }
}
else
{
   echo "Oops! Parameter not set !! ");
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
if (!isset($_POST['password']) || trim($_POST['password'])==="" ) {// If password field 1 is empty
      echo("Oops! Password is required! Try again. ");
     exit();
} 
if (!isset($_POST['password1']) || trim($_POST['password1'])==="" ) {// If password field 2 is empty
      echo("Oops! Password is required! Try again. ");
     exit();
} 
if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password1'] ) {// If password field 1 &2 did not match
      echo("Oops! Password did not match! Try again.");
     exit();
} 
//Contiune....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$password1 = $_POST['password1'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

 if(!empty($password) && !empty(password1))
    {
         if($password == $password)
         {
             // your executable code
             echo("Password match!");
         }
    } 
    else
    {
         echo("Oops! Password did not match! Try again. ");
         exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
if (empty($_POST['password1']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
      echo("Oops! Password did not match! Try again. ");
     exit();
} 
else{
}
```

to:

```
if (empty($_POST['password1']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
      echo("please check ! at least one password is not filled. ");
     exit();
} 
else{
}
```